# How to connect make MS Sql Server Connection in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-connect, mssql

I need to make connection in magento say a php file where i can make connection to MS SQL Server. can anyone please let me know how can i do this.

Answer (score 6):

As Magento is heavily tied to MySQL you will need to use plain PHP or try it with the Zend Framework DB Adapter: Check out the `mssql_connect` [function on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) and [Zend_Db_Adapter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

Also you need to make sure the needed MSSQL extension is enabled in your php.ini file, for example `extension=php_mssql.dll`

To store the username, password and host I suggest you use the same way in `app/etc/local.xml` just as Magento does it. You can then afterwards access the data in your PHP file.

`app/etc/local.xml` example:

```
    <resources>
        <default_setup>
            <!-- your default mysql setup here -->
        </default_setup>
        <mssql_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[dbuser]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[dbpassword]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
            </connection>
        </mssql_setup>
    </resources>
```

access the data from `local.xml` to use in your PHP script:

```
$host = (string)$config->global->resources->mssql_setup->connection->host;
$username = (string)$config->global->resources->mssql_setup->connection->username,
$password = (string)$config->global->resources->mssql_setup->connection->password;
$dbname = (string)$config->global->resources->mssql_setup->connection->dbname;
```